# How to find latest status of the day in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server question that I'm trying to figure out at work:

There is a table with a status field which can contain a status called "Participate."  I am only trying to find records if the latest status of the day is "Participate" and only if the status changed on the same day from another status to "Participate."

I don't want any records where the status was already "Participate."  It must have changed to that status on the same day.  You can tell when the status was changed by the datetime field ChangedOn.

In the sample below I would only want to bring back ID 1880 since the status of "Participated" has the latest timestamp.   I would not bring back ID 1700 since the last record is "Other," and I would not bring back ID 1600 since "Participated" is the only status of that day.

```
ChangedOn          Status            ID
02/01/17 15:23     Terminated        1880
02/01/17 17:24     Participated      1880
02/01/17 09:00     Other             1880
01/31/17 01:00     Terminated        1700
01/31/17 02:00     Participated      1700
01/31/17 03:00     Other             1700
01/31/17 02:00     Participated      1600
```

I was thinking of using a Window function, but I'm not sure how to get started on this.  It's been a few months since I've written a query like this so I'm a bit out of practice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cast(ChangedOn as date)
                                order by ChangedOn desc
                               ) as seqnum,
             sum(case when status <> 'Participate' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cast(ChangedOn as date)) as num_nonparticipate
      from t
     ) t
where (seqnum = 1 and ChangedOn = 'Participate') and
      num_nonparticipate > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with other sample data,

```
declare @t table(ChangedOn datetime,Status varchar(50),ID int)
insert into @t VALUES
('02/01/17 15:23',     'Terminated'        ,1880)
,('02/01/17 17:24',     'Participated'      ,1880)
,('02/01/17 09:00',     'Other'             ,1880)
,('01/31/17 01:00',     'Terminated'        ,1700)
,('01/31/17 02:00',     'Participated'      ,1700)
,('01/31/17 03:00',     'Other'             ,1700)
,('01/31/17 02:00',     'Participated'      ,1600)

;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY id
            ,cast(ChangedOn AS DATE) ORDER BY ChangedOn DESC
            ) AS seqnum
    FROM @t
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte c
WHERE seqnum = 1
    AND STATUS = 'Participated'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT id
        FROM cte c1
        WHERE seqnum > 1
            AND c.id = c1.id
        )
```

2nd query,this is better

here CTE is same

```
SELECT *
FROM cte c
WHERE seqnum = 1
AND STATUS = 'Participated'
AND EXISTS (
SELECT id
FROM cte c1
WHERE  STATUS != 'Participated'
    AND c.id = c1.id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this?

```
 WITH sample_table(ChangedOn,Status,ID)AS(
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'02/01/2017 15:23'),'Terminated',1880 UNION ALL
    SELECT '02/01/2017 17:24','Participated',1880 UNION ALL
    SELECT '02/01/2017 09:00','Other',1880 UNION ALL
    SELECT '01/31/2017 01:00','Terminated',1700 UNION ALL
    SELECT '01/31/2017 02:00','Participated',1700 UNION ALL
    SELECT '01/31/2017 03:00','Other',1700 UNION ALL
    SELECT '01/31/2017 02:00','Participated',1600
)
SELECT ID FROM (
SELECT *
      ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID,CONVERT(VARCHAR,ChangedOn,112) ORDER BY ChangedOn) AS rn
      ,COUNT(0)OVER(PARTITION BY ID,CONVERT(VARCHAR,ChangedOn,112)) AS cnt 
      ,CASE WHEN Status<>'Participated' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ss
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Status!='Participated' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)OVER(PARTITION BY ID,CONVERT(VARCHAR,ChangedOn,112)) AS OtherStatusCnt
FROM sample_table
) AS t WHERE t.rn=t.cnt AND t.Status='Participated' AND t.OtherStatusCnt>0
```

--Return:
1880